Setting boundary condition for urban catchment flow direction operation
I am trying to delineate individual catchments for a large number of kerb inlet pits from a LiDAR DEM using open source tools (QGIS, WhiteBox).
In areas where the LiDAR has sampled verge elevations to be lower than the road, flow direction is obviously shown to be leaving the road onto the verge. However, in reality there is a kerb preventing this from happening and the water will flow longitudinally along the road rather than over topping the kerb. I have a vector polygon representing the extents of the road,
Is there's any way to force the flow to not exit (entry is still allowed) the defined polygon and take the next lowest cell without crossing the polygon boundary?
I have tried burning streams along the kerb lines but this has the effect of forcing flow along the kerbs through intersections where in reality flow may be diverted depending on the topology.
